# How to render Video Page when the button is clicked before taking the next action in React.js

Tags: reactjs, video

how can I show a video when the button is clicked and then it performs an
action , so step by step:

- user lands to the main page
- user clicks on the button that should take him/her to home page
- I used useNavigate to change the route of the page to /home, but before doing that, I want the user to see short video.

so far this is what I came up with, but it doesnt work

````
const Main = (props) => {
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const playVideo = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <video src={video}></video>
            </div>
        )
    }

    const handleClickHome = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        await playVideo()
        return (
            navigate("/home")
        )
    }

  

    return (

        <div className={classes.main} >
                    <button onClick={handleClickHome} className={classes.button}>    <h2> LET ME IN </h2> </button>
        </div >
    );
}

export default Main ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can show your video by clicking the button and use under below event for navigation.

```
  document.getElementById('videoId').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
    function myHandler(e) {
        // do navigation
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not sure I understood your solution. so this is also more JS code,  right? I am trying to implement it React.js . The video only needs to be shown when the button is clicked, for couple of seconds and then comes the navigation action. Can you please explain what do you mean exactly by under below event for navigation?

Comment: ok I misunderstood at first , so check this one and let m know is it something you are looking for?open the console then press the button
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ubrjcb?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: hey, no did not, everything is logged on the console, and seems like everything is in order but the video is still not playing